# Kafka performance(writes/sec) drastically drops on increasing number of events/messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, producer

**Summary**

I am trying to benchmark an off-the-shelf kafka (3 nodes) cluster. I am using the default configuration. Following are the setup details:

```
Total nodes         = 3
Zookeeper           = node1
Workers             = node1, node2 and node3
Config of each node = 4 core, 15 GB
Kafka Version       = 2.7.0
Scala Version       = 2.13
```

[Here are the node configurations](https://github.com/Udit-Jindal/KafkaLoadTester/tree/master/node%20configs)

The first bench mark objective is to check the `write speed`. To do that, I wrote a java program which creates multiple threads, one producer/thread and writes to the kafka cluster concurrently.

I am noting the start time and end time to measure the time taken.

[Here is the code](https://github.com/Udit-Jindal/KafkaLoadTester/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sta/data/kafka/kafkaloadtester/KafkaLoadTester.java)

[Here are the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBWvK.png)

[Here are the Stats](https://github.com/Udit-Jindal/KafkaLoadTester/tree/master/Stats)

**The issue**

As I am increasing the number of event, the write/sec is getting reduced.

```
| Messages    | Write/Sec |
|:----------- |:----------|
| 63,965      | 21,236.72 |
| 987,123     | 57,151.63 |
| 20,000,000  | 39,503.60 |
| 50,000,000  | 14,311.95 |
| 99,990,052  | 11,113.97 |
| 300,000,000 | 10,811.26 |
```

**Questions**

- Why the performance is hampering when inserting more data?
- What kind of tuning can I do to improve the write speed?
- If my testing methodology is correct or not? Is there any better way to benchmark a Kafka cluster?

**Notes**

- This is my first post on stack overflow, so kindly let me know if I can improve anything in the question.

Comment: Performance hampering when the load peaks is quite to be expected, however, it's very tricky to measure. The bottleneck might actually be your testing program. Observing CPU, Memory, I/O and network traffic on both cluster and testing client is a must to get some reasonable conslusions.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Thank you for your comment. I am not sure if we can say this a "peak" because, the rate of insertions is constant at the test-client's end. The write/sec is getting decreased from Kafka's end.

I checked the stats but couldn't find any meaningful pattern out of them.
I have edited the question and added link to stats.
Link is : https://github.com/Udit-Jindal/KafkaLoadTester/tree/master/Stats

Can you please check if there is any pattern or meaningful insight? Thanks.

Comment: The methodology looks fine then, so it looks like Kafka's performance is affected by the number of active messages. I thought they use a kind of DB and not keep all in memory, but my experience with Kafka is limited to the proof-of-concept (we don't use it, because it's not optimized for our use case).